# use local files on web page

Tags: css, image, firefox, firefox-addon, local-files

I'm trying to use local images on a web page in FireFox. The problem is whatever I do, I see a security message and images won't load:

```
Security Error: Content at http://domain.com/ may not load or link to file:///E:/path/to/file/file.png.
```

I put the following content into `user.js` and copied that file in FireFox profile directory.

```
user_pref("capability.policy.policynames", "localfilelinks");
user_pref("capability.policy.localfilelinks.sites",  'http://domain.com');
user_pref("capability.policy.localfilelinks.checkloaduri.enabled", "allAccess");
```

What I want to do is add css file and use that for styling the page.

**Edit:**
I wrote an extension which alters HTTP response and replace remote css files with local ones. But as I said , Firefox prevent local css files from loading.

**Edit 2**
Please do **NOT**  remove `firefox-addon` tag from this question.

Comment: And what's the question?

Comment: @WladimirPalant  I want to use local image on web page!

Comment: Is there a reason why you cannot put the image in the same folder as the page and use just `<img src=file.png alt="?">`?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela you can't do that with local images because it is not allowed for security reasons.

Comment: @cimmanon, it works fine when the referring HTML document is local. It’s not clear at all what the question is about (first an image was mentioned, then a CSS file, etc.).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I edited my question, take a look at it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do this - access to the `file://` protocol has been locked down for a reason. If your goal is to replace images with local data then just don't use the `file://` protocol, there are plenty of others available. You can use the [`data:` protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/data_URIs) for example. This is the SO icon as a `data:` URL:

> data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8%2F9hAAABrUlEQVR42mNkwAOepOgxMTD9mwhk5gDxQSB2l5l15SeyGkYGAuBJMtAQ5n%2BrgcwgIF4ENCCeJAOghvADXbIHqNoEyK0BGtKK14DXU9lAThZiYPw%2FXTTr92uId3SVgKoPA8WkgNxIoCErsBrwdhoL57%2F%2FTGeATC0gfgVUMRlo%2B2zRjD8vn6RrmzH8ZT4E5IOU%2BgAN2YNhwMOJ%2FEy8bJ%2BVgGYnAQ3K%2Ff%2BfkQco%2FAYYDjP%2BfeHs%2FfNQyub%2FN44NQJe0ysy5VI83DF5M5pRkY%2FmVyfCfIRtomNB%2Fpv9v%2F%2F9infbnucgZ5l%2FMW8T7HvxDMWB9hT3nXwbmrH%2F%2FmO4Bubc4Wb%2Ff9W09%2BuNmjwQPP%2FvHNHaWXwX%2FGf7LsjD9k%2BFLZ3iKEQYbKmy1%2FjKwXIXx%2F%2F1nfPvvP%2FMVJsZ%2FRzlYfpwX4nj%2FT5zrNbtK8evlWGNhcYU3Px%2FDR%2Bf%2FDExGQK4pEKsCseJ%2FoDKgF0AGMvxjZLIP79xzCMWA3Jyc%2FyB68pQpGGEyuyJEhJXhtwYLELMx%2FNL9wcDRcfqLwjOYegwDYGxcAFkNbQxgIALgNIBUQBUDAFi2whGNUZ3eAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC

This URL is easily generated:

```
var url = "data:image/png;base64," + btoa(imageData);
```

Alternatively you could use `resource://` URLs that can be mapped to directories on disk using `nsIResProtocolHandler` but that's [more complicated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_code_modules/Using#Programmatically_adding_aliases). Keep in mind that all contents of the mapped directory become accessible to all websites. You should make sure that it doesn't contain any sensitive information.

**Asker:***
I added content of the link:

```
var ioService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1"]
                          .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIIOService);
var resProt = ioService.getProtocolHandler("resource")
                       .QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIResProtocolHandler);

var aliasFile = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"]
                          .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);
aliasFile.initWithPath("/some/absolute/path");

var aliasURI = ioService.newFileURI(aliasFile);
resProt.setSubstitution("myalias", aliasURI);

// assuming the code modules are in the alias folder itself
```

Comment: There are about 3,000 images in those css file, so I cannot use `data` protocol, I'll try second solution!

Comment: @Death: Please have a look at the warning I added at the end of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

That is correct.  Attempting to use images directly off of the user's filesystem is a security vulnerability.  Newer browsers have implemented the FileReader API, which allows you to access the user's files in a safe way.

Here are a few examples:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

http://html5demos.com/file-api

Comment: What I want to do is load a css file locally, images are in that file

Comment: I don't think that will be possible because you don't have access to the filesystem itself (where are the relative paths to the images relative from?).  FileReader gives you access just about everything about a file *except* where it lives.

Comment: Look, what I'm doing is I wrote an extension which alters HTTP response and replace remote CSS file with local ones, So I guest I can add any access that I need to my extension. Can you help me now?

Comment: I cannot help you any further because what you're now asking for is beyond my area of expertise.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it's worth the [effort](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/test/httpserver/README), but you can use [`httpd.js`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Httpd.js/HTTP_server_for_unit_tests) as an XPCOM component.

Edit: I just realized that the [Add-on SDK offers `httpd.js`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/packages/api-utils/httpd.html)